# ReferenceError in ScriptEngine eval

Tags: java, scriptengine, javascript-engine

I'm using the JavaScript engine in JDK 7. Is there a way to evaluate an expression like `a||b` to false if `a` and `b` are undefined, instead of throwing the exception `ReferenceError: "a" is not defined.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

I took the following approach to achieve what I wanted. I was evaluating the expression and if that expression was failing, I was adding the undefined variable to the context and try to reevaluate again.